# LinkedIn search for people

Tags: linkedin

How to find people who have recently worked in X company but currently they are working for different company?

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on the Search button
2. Then Select the past company on the right side bar:

   [image]
3. Based on your selection, you will see the list of people updating.

Comment: I think second point should be: **Search for people with filters**, and then select company (past, current) from right side.
Simply clicking on search button, right side menu is not showing.